# The event of the document is not triggered, when it is on a disabled element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend, dom-events

When I give the document a `mouseup` event, if the mouse in a disabled element and I released the button. The document `mouseup` event handler can't fire. 
How should I do let the handler be called?

Example:

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  console.log('mouseup')
}, true)

const changeBtn = document.getElementById('change')
const testBtn = document.getElementById('test')

changeBtn.onclick = () => {
  testBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true)
}
testBtn.onclick = () => {
  console.log('testBtn click')
}
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
<button id="change">change</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS set [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on [`:disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) elements:

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  console.log('mouseup')
}, true)

const changeBtn = document.getElementById('change')
const testBtn = document.getElementById('test')

changeBtn.onclick = () => {
  testBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true)
}
testBtn.onclick = () => {
  console.log('testBtn click')
}
```

```css
*:disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
<button id="change">change</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way? I may not want it to trigger bubbling or capture, its side effects must be too great

Comment: Using `pointer-events: none` makes the element transparent to mouse events. If you don't want to use capture, don't set `true` as the 2nd param of `addEventListener`.

Comment: I just want the document to trigger the event. I do n’t want his parent element to trigger the event, but using pointer-events: none will cause the parent element to also trigger the event. I set the third property of addEventListener to false, but the parent element Of events will still trigger

Comment: That's a tricky one. You can add to the parent's event handler a check that excludes disabled disabled elements or their children using `.closest()`.